# How to add user with a limited folder access in centos 7 nginx

Tags: nginx

I have setup a server with multiple websites on digital ocean CentOS7 Nginx.

The actual folder structure of my root area is as below

```
Website A : /var/www/html/website-A 
Website B : /var/www/html/website-B 
Website-C : /var/www/html/website-C
```

So how I can allow a sub user to access a only particular directory, for example `website-A`?

I have a different developer team who is working on remote location so I have to give them access to folder `/var/www/html/website-A`.
Only they can't see the other 2 websites and folders.

I have created a user with the following command

```
useradd -m -d /var/www/html/website-A/ -c "welsiteA Owner" -U websiteAteam
```

And for setting a password for the user

```
passwd websiteAteam
```

When user is logged in from the `FTP` it opens up the `website-A` correctly .

But the problem is he can still go back and access the other `Website-B` & `Website-C` directories.

So how can I restrict them doing that? Or can I stop them downloading or adding or editing files in other directories ?

Can you please guide ?

Comment: You could use file ACLs, e.g. `setfacl` to create an ACL. Or if it's possible to change the directory's groups without breaking the web sites, you could give each directory a different group and put your users into suitable groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First decide what permissions you want to add.

rwx =
read
write
execute

```
setfacl -m u:user1:rwx /var/www/html/website-A
setfacl -m u:user2:rwx /var/www/html/website-B
setfacl -m u:user3:rwx /var/www/html/website-C
```

or for group

```
setfacl -m g:group1:rwx /var/www/html/website-A
setfacl -m g:group2:rwx /var/www/html/website-B
setfacl -m g:group3:rwx /var/www/html/website-C
```

Add user to a group

```
usermod -aG group1 user1
```

Comment: It worked like a charm but still the view it is still rendering .. For example var/www/html/website1 has been blocked for user 2 but var/www/html folder still can render the folder name when the user clicks on it it says Permission denided

Comment: Remember read and execute allow to see what is inside. gefacl /var/www/html will show you permissions. You can take it away from anyone except apache the owner and group for /var/www/html should always be apache or nginx, with ACL you can set proper level of access to each directory. Besides with chown - R apache:apache /var/www/htmk you will set it. Chmod changes permissions, so read about it too. However I would just set up with ACL to take away the permissions to not let them read the content of two other directories.. - d sets the default ACL permission for group.

Comment: See this https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-access-control-lists